# Option in Option menu are not visible instead it is showing only white blank space,here are my menu xml and main activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

**the [button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmCh0.jpg) more information is not visible!!!!**

**xml of menu** :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item
    android:id="@+id/more_information"
    android:title="@string/action_mnn"
    />
</menu>
```

**main activity** :-

```
package com.example.yashchaudhary.modernartui;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
 }
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.more_information:
            return true;
        default :
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
         }

      }
}
```

**screenshot after clickin on 3 dots**

Comment: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/UmCh0.jpg
here is the link to screenshot

Comment: What is your theme? Looks like the menu item is there, either not visible as it is in white, or the string is empty.

Comment: Try to `clean` the project and `rebuild` it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a Theme specific for the action bar in the activity layout

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"     
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar"
.../>
```

Removing the theme property solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar" android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar"/>
```

Removing the theme attribute will resolve this problem.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add to the item on the menu xml

```
android:orderInCategory="100"
```

and add `break;` after

```
case R.id.more_information:
            return true;
```